# grails.gsp.view.dir works in dev but not when deployed as war

Tags: tomcat, grails

I've been trying to take advantage of the grails.gsp.view.dir which would seem to be the ideal solution when integrating with a cloud-based CMS.  And when I used Grails run-app this works fine, but as soon as I build it as a war file and deploy it to Tomcat (I'm using version 7) it no longer pays attention to this directive and uses the default WEB-INF directory.

I'm using some pretty standard plugins (mail, webflow, jodatime) so I don't believe they are the issue although I have yet to start with a brand new app.  I'll try that next.  I thought maybe this was a bug in 2.1.1 so I upgraded to 2.3, but I still have the same issue.  Is there something I need to be doing in my build config to a) tell it to deploy my views elsewhere and b) have it use that deployed directory?  Any ideas would be helpful,

Thanks

Comment: but what directory you're expecting after deploying as a WAR file?

Comment: Hi @Igor Artamonov, On my local, I have a directory '\temp\grails\grails-app\views'.  I thus set the grails.gsp.view.dir = 'temp\grails\' and when I do a run-app it does read all views from this directory.  But when I make a war file and put it into my local tomcat instance's webapps folder it no longer reads from temp/grails/grails-app/views and instead reads from tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/grails-app/views.  Kind of annoying.  I tried this on my dev box and our production server and regardless of the value for grails.gsp.view.dir it reads from the WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm rather surprised no one else ran into this problem, but it appears the Grails documentation for **grails.gsp.view.dir** is incorrect.  I set the value as '/temp/grails/' with the trailing / as the documentation specified, but as I mentioned above it works when running grails-app but not when you deploy it as a war file.

I did some code review and I noticed this config setting is passed by the GroovyPagesGrailsPlugin to the GroovyPageResourceLoader (It's nice to work with open source).  The GroovyPageResourceLoader had a nice debug statement that showed what resource path it was trying to use, so I turned it on and in dev it showed it was searching in the path:  **'/temp/grails/grails-app/views'** as one might expect.  However, when I deployed it as a war and checked the log it showed it as: **/temp/grails/WEB-INF/grails-app/views'**.  So I added the WEB-INF directory to my temp/grails and sure enough it works.  Not sure if I should create a JIRA ticket for this, but the documentation should be updated.